# Fixing phpMyAdmin errors

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

All,

Per:
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/support/
we are supposed to ask support Qs here for phpmyadmin.

Getting this error:

"Failed to read configuration file  This usually means there is a syntax error in it, please check any errors shown below."

But the box below is blank.

The only thing I added was a timeout value of:

$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 19200

And I used to be able to set this to:

60*60*24*3

or 3 days, so as developer not re-logging in all the time.

Even after commenting out the $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] line the system still errors with a blank red line.

I do not see any log file defined in the config.inc.php config file, so have no idea where to look for the current errors.

All help appreciated!

Cheers!

OMR

Comment: Shouldn't that line have a ; after it? What happens if you delete it altogether?  Apache error log usually has some hints - typically in /var/log/httpd/?????.log or /var/log/apache/??????.log

Comment: Alsi, stackoverflow may be more appropriate according to your link (but I think this is on topic here to)

Comment: Davidgo,  The ';" fixed that line, but still getting the Red Blank error line after login, so not reading anything.  Was importing tables when this all went down, so used the cmd line to finish, but can't actually login still.

Comment: Oh Stackoverflow is recommended, but that throws you to SuperUser when you want to ask a phpmyadmin Q!

Comment: davidgo,  Must have been something hanging in the DB as I pulled up MySQL Workbench and after that phpMyAdmin went back to working!  Cheers